# What is the difference between DELTA & TOTAL columns in dba_hist_sqlstat Oracle?

Tags: database-administration, oracle-11g

I am using the following query to measure the performance improvement between two views

```
SELECT PARSING_SCHEMA_NAME,
    SQL_TEXT,
    OPTIMIZER_COST,
    FETCHES_TOTAL,
    FETCHES_DELTA,
    EXECUTIONS_TOTAL,
    EXECUTIONS_DELTA,
    PARSE_CALLS_TOTAL,
    PARSE_CALLS_DELTA,
    DISK_READS_TOTAL,
    DISK_READS_DELTA,
    BUFFER_GETS_TOTAL,
    BUFFER_GETS_DELTA,
    ROWS_PROCESSED_TOTAL,
    ROWS_PROCESSED_DELTA,
    CPU_TIME_TOTAL,
    CPU_TIME_DELTA,
    ELAPSED_TIME_TOTAL,
    ELAPSED_TIME_DELTA,
    elapsed_time_delta / 1000 / 1000 AS elapsed_sec,
    stat.snap_id,
    TO_CHAR(SNAP.END_INTERVAL_TIME, 'dd.mm hh24:mi:ss') AS SNAPTIME,
    txt.sql_id
FROM dba_hist_sqlstat stat,
    dba_hist_sqltext txt,
    dba_hist_snapshot snap
WHERE stat.sql_id = txt.sql_id
    AND STAT.SNAP_ID = SNAP.SNAP_ID
    AND SNAP.BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME >= SYSDATE - 10
    AND (
        LOWER(SQL_TEXT) LIKE '%view1_name%'
        OR LOWER(SQL_TEXT) LIKE '%view2_name%'
        )
    AND PARSING_SCHEMA_NAME NOT IN ('SYS', 'SYSMAN')
ORDER BY elapsed_time_delta ASC;
```

What is the difference between DELTA & TOTAL columns in the above query? Which set of columns are to be considered when measuring the performance change between the views?

Answer (score 0):

CPU Time Total means that your statement used CPU for that amount of seconds. It's the cumulative value of CPU time parsing/executing/fetching.

CPU Time Delta is measuring usage between polling cycles.

The logic of this is the following: it helps you separate those sessions which are currently using a lot of CPU time (sort them by CPU Delta) versus those which have, over their lifetime, used a lot of CPU time (sort them by CPU Total).